# Power Apps Canvas question, dueling Lookup columns

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

Greetings new to Power Apps Canvas.  We got a supporting Microsoft list with two lookup columns. Created a Power Apps Canvas for the user interface.  Use the Canvas to publish a new record to the list.  Question is; how to have each dropdown reset/clear the other.  So, if the user selects an option from the first dropdown it would reset/clear the second dropdown and vice-versa.

[Power Apps Canvas snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmt9b.png)

So as shown in the image, if Exterior List Item is selected first and then Interior List Item is selected the Exterior List Item dropdown clears and vice-versa.

Any suggestion are greatly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this OnChange of DataCardValue4 property: If(DataCardValue4.Selected.Value<>Blank(),Reset(DataCardValue6),false)

Write this OnChange of DataCardValue6 property:
If(DataCardValue6.Selected.Value<>Blank(),Reset(DataCardValue4),false)

Comment: Thank you blini ! Prefect result, I was caught up trying;  IF(! IsBlank(DataCardValue4.Selected.Value),Reset(DataCardValue6),false)  and even trying the keyword Not instead of the !

Comment: @zzmgd6 I'm glad to hear that, if my answer was useful feel free to accept it as a correct answer.